# How to pass class type arguments in jruby

Tags: java, jruby

Say I need to translate the following Java code in jruby:

```
Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

In jruby, without type arguments it'd look like this:

```
topic_count_map = HashMap.new
```

But how do I pass type arguments?

Comment: check this - http://ruby.11.x6.nabble.com/JRuby-gt-Java-using-generics-td3459866.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. The type arguments are not specified in `JRuby`

```
topic_count_map = HashMap.new
topic_count_map.put("foo", 100)
topic_count_map.get("foo")
```

Read: [JRuby Basics](http://railscasts.com/episodes/376-jruby-basics?view=asciicast)

Comment: I mean type arguments, not just arguments. This part <String, Integer> from Map<String, Integer>

Comment: That's what I mean in the answer

Comment: @Arty Isn't that what the answer... answers?

Comment: I see. I missed the first line and just read the example. Thanks.